# How to swap input for external diff/merge tool in gitKraken?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, merge, diff, gitkraken

I use Visual Studio Code as an external diff and merge tool for gitKraken. Internal gitKraken tool represents the changes correctly but if I try to open them in the external tool then all added lines are shown in red (removed) and all removed lines are shown in green (added). Does someone know how to swap the windows, so the changes have correct color?
See images below to understand the question better:

[GitKraken example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJWNQ.png)

[VS Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns0Gb.png)